# removing "(1)" from multiple file names that span multiple directories

Tags: powershell, filenames

So I was redownloading my google drive backup and I noticed that in every file no matter how deep in my directory and or subdirectory it had in its name a "(1)" and I was wondering about removing this.
Iv gotten to `get-childitem . | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace(" (1)", "") }` but thats only for this directory and I need to go deeper a lot deeper.
Thanks in advance.

update: got to "get-childitem -recurse | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace " (1)", ""}"
however it throws an error:
rename-item : Source and destination path must be different.
At line:1 char:26

- ... lditem -recurse | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace " (1)", ""}
- ```
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\Opti\D...rgs (1)\lib (1):String) [Rename-Item], IOException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

edit: Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\My\Root\Path" -Filter "*(1)*" -Recurse | Foreach {Rename-Item -Path $*.FullName -NewName $*.Name.Replace('(1)','')}
^ this is what worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\My\Root\Path" -Recurse | Foreach {Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $_.Name.Replace('(1)','')}
```

Comment: You could also add  `-Filter "* (1).*" ` to the `Get-ChildItem ` to avoid unnecessarily calling `Rename-Item` when no rename is necessary.

Comment: Thats correct.  `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\My\Root\Path" -Filter "*(1)*" -Recurse | Foreach {Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $_.Name.Replace('(1)','')}`

Comment: Im glad to hear it did(:

Answer (score 0):

Use the recurse flag to search nested folders.

`Get-Childitem -Path "C:\My\Root\Path" -Recurse |` [do stuff]

Comment: can you elaborate it just responds with rename-item : Cannot rename because item at 'v16 (1)' does not exist.
At line:1 char:37
+ ... em -Recurse |  foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace(" (1)", "") }
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
for every file